# Kafka Streams: how to convert data types?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka's Streams API with topology builder.
I would like to know how I can do to have a processor that can convert one data type to another, so the next processor in the pipeline can use it.

As a simple use case :

```
[topic]--(string)-->[processor: parse json]--(object)-->[processor 2]--(object)-->[sink]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to convert the message *values* in a Kafka topic from String to JSON.

You only need two parts:

- The code to convert String to JSON (or Pojo).  Pick whatever you need here, e.g. there are a couple of Java libraries available to make this easy.
- In Kafka Streams, define (1) a value serde for `String` for reading from your source topic, and (2) define a corresponding value serde for writing the JSON data (or Pojo) to the destination topic.  Serdes are required to materialize your data when/where needed (e.g., writing your Pojos to Kafka requires materialization).

See the example code under https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview for how to e.g. use JSON with Apache Kafka's Streams API.